# Mobile Viewport issue intermittant

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

sorry for the mess below but I've spent too long now trying to fix this myself so time to back down and ask for help!

Screenshots to explain the issue:

http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/img/1.PNG
http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/img/2.PNG

Basically sometimes the webpage works on mobile fine, and sometimes everything in the  is off to the right so you only see part of it without having to horizontal scroll. if you refresh the page 4-5 times it usually falls back into mobile view on its own.

the weblink is http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/ just incase the problem isn't in the CSS below but the JS for the text animation.

thanks

```
/* Google fonts & font family
==================================================*/
@import url(font-awesome.min.css);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700);

/* General
==================================================*/

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.8;
    color: #999

}

.no-padding {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.no-padding [class^="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.main-container {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s
}

.uppercase {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.h-30 {
    height: 30px
}

.h-10 {
    height: 10px
}

.color {
    color: #02FA79;
    font-size: 11px;
}


/* typography
==================================================*/

h1 {
    color: #393939;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
    color: #393939;
}

h5 {
    color: #02FA79;
}


/* preloader
==================================================*/

#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    /* change if the mask should be a color other than white */
    z-index: 1000;
    /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

.pre-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.spinner {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.double-bounce1,
.double-bounce2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #02FA79;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%,
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.0)
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%,
    100% {
        transform: scale(0.0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}





/* box-intro
==================================================*/

.box-intro {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}

.box-intro .table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.box-intro em {
    font-style: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

b i:last-child {
    color: #02FA79 !important;
}

.box-intro h5 {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 1.7
}


/* mouse effect */

.mouse {
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 42px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -12px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid #888;
    -webkit-animation: intro 1s;
    animation: intro 1s;
}

.scroll {
    display: block;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 6px auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #888;
    -webkit-animation: finger 2s infinite;
    animation: finger 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes intro {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes finger {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}

@keyframes finger {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
}


/* text rotate */

.box-headline {
    font-size: 130px;
    line-height: 1.0;
}

.box-words-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.box-words-wrapper b {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.box-words-wrapper b.is-visible {
    position: relative;
}

.no-js .box-words-wrapper b {
    opacity: 0;
}

.no-js .box-words-wrapper b.is-visible {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 .box-words-wrapper {
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 i,
.box-headline.rotate-2 em {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 b {
    opacity: 0;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 i {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(90deg);
    transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.is-visible .box-headline.rotate-2 i {
    opacity: 1;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 i.in {
    -webkit-animation: box-rotate-2-in 0.4s forwards;
    animation: box-rotate-2-in 0.4s forwards;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 i.out {
    -webkit-animation: box-rotate-2-out 0.4s forwards;
    animation: box-rotate-2-out 0.4s forwards;
}

.box-headline.rotate-2 em {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}

.no-csstransitions .box-headline.rotate-2 i {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

.no-csstransitions .box-headline.rotate-2 i em {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.no-csstransitions .box-headline.rotate-2 .is-visible i {
    opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes box-rotate-2-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0deg);
    }
}

@keyframes box-rotate-2-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(90deg);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(90deg);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-10deg);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-10deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0deg);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes box-rotate-2-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-100deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-90deg);
    }
}

@keyframes box-rotate-2-out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-100deg);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-100deg);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-90deg);
        transform: translateZ(-20px) rotateX(-90deg);
    }
}




/* footer
==================================================*/

footer {
    padding: 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f5f5f5
}

.copyright {
    color: #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* backto top
==================================================*/

.cd-top {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #02FA79;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s .3s;
}

.cd-top.cd-is-visible,
.cd-top.cd-fade-out,
.no-touch .cd-top:hover {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    transition: opacity .3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-top.cd-is-visible {
    /* the button becomes visible */
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.cd-top.cd-fade-out {
    opacity: .5;
}

.no-touch .cd-top:hover,
.no-touch .cd-top:focus {
    background-color: #02FA79;
    opacity: 1;
    color: #fff;
}


/* About page
==================================================*/

.top-bar {
    color: #333;
    padding: 150px 0 150px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)), url(../img/01.jpg);
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, .8), rgba(255, 255, 255, .8)), url(../img/01.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-bar h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.top-bar p {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #777;
}

.top-bar p a {
    color: #777;
}

.top-bar p a:hover,
.top-bar p a:focus {
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.social-ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.social-ul li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: left;
}

.social-ul li a {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #555;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.social-ul li a:hover {
    color: #888;
}


/* Services page
==================================================*/

.size-50 {
    font-size: 50px;
}

.service-box {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.service-box h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
}


/* contact page
==================================================*/

.details-text i {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.textarea-contact {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: relative;
}

.textarea-contact textarea {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #9a9a9a;
    resize: none;
}

.textarea-contact > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #cdcdcd;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.input-contact {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.input-contact input[type="text"] {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #9a9a9a;
}

.input-contact > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #cdcdcd;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}

.input-contact > span.active,
.textarea-contact > span.active {
    color: #02FA79;
    font-size: 10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.contact-info {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.contact-info i {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #02FA79;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 33px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.contact-info p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.btn-box {
    background: #02FA79;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.btn-box:hover,
.btn-box:focus {
    background: #F5B700;
    color: #fff;
}


/* single project page
==================================================*/

.cat-ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.cat-ul li i {
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #02FA79;
}


/* Responsive media queries
==================================================*/

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .portfolio .categories-grid span {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .portfolio .categories-grid .categories ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .portfolio .categories-grid .categories ul li a {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .col-md-6 h3 {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 670px) {
    .box-headline {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
    .box-intro h5 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .box-primary-nav a {
        padding: 5px 1em;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .box-primary-nav {
        padding: 80px 0 0;
    }
    .box-primary-nav .box-social a {
        font-size: 23px;
    }
    .top-bar h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    .portfolio .categories-grid .categories ul li {
        float: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .box-headline {
        font-size: 80px;
    }
    .box-intro h5 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .main-container {
        padding: 50px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .box-headline {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    .box-intro h5 {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .top-bar h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }


}

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">


    <section class="box-intro">
         <div class="table-cell">
                    <h1 class="box-headline letters rotate-2">
                        <span class="box-words-wrapper">
                            <b class="is-visible">design.</b>
                            <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;coding.</b>
                            <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;graphics.</b>
                              <b>imagination.</b>

                     </span>
                    </h1>
                   <h5>The perfect combination to your websites success </h5>
                 </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue at all. It would help to add browser info and exactly what you've tried for questions such as this.

Comment: As I said for some reason it is very intermittant, if I close the mobile tab off and past the link directly into safari again usually 1-3 times it will happen. I have played around with <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> to all possible combinations of scaling and completely removed scalable alll together. I'll post some screenshots

Comment: Just reloaded the page 20 times and couldn't recreate the issue. Just carry out some basic debugging: remove elements one-by-one, inspect the broken page and define which element is creating the horizontal scroll, unhook JS etc.

Comment: http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/img/1.PNG

Comment: http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/img/2.PNG

Comment: Ok so narrowing it down a little, If I click the refresh button on my iPhone the page goes to the right, if I click the url bar and just press go it appears in the center of the mobile where it should be, this is happening on both my device and my partners

Comment: have again tried that with no joy. What version of iOS are you both using?

Comment: try wrapping your custom.js in `$(document).ready(function(){})` instead of `$(window).load(function () {})` as I believe the `window.load` function was deprecated in jQuery v3.0

Comment: 10 and 11. Video uploading maybe it will help maybe it won't. Maybe I'm creating the error and a genuine visitor will never experience it haha. I will try that now thanks

Comment: Page wouldn't load, stuck at the loader screen. heres a video http://crazy-pixels.co.uk/test/img/1.MOV

Comment: .box-words-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
 width: 100% !important;
} FIXED IT. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display: table seems to be causing the problem. Change to display block and you will be able to control the width of the elements.

Update: .box-words-wrapper was causing the problem. Css rule added below.

```
.box-intro {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.box-intro .table-cell {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.box-words-wrapper { 
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%!important; 
}
```

Comment: Maybe span .box-words-wrapper has a width of 910px that might be messing with it too. span.box-words-wrapper { width: 100% !important; }. It will need an !important to over-ride.

Comment: this sorted it! Thank you very much! .box-words-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
 width: 100% !important;
}